# Passing strings to functions

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I know this is a stupid question but I don't know exactly how to search for it.

I want to feed a parameter into a function to conditionally run code.

In the example below, if I specify the word single in the function call, I would like it to run the line of code at the top and return the string "This".  If I specify any other word, I want it to run the second line of code and return "That".

Example:

```
def condfunc(myvar):
    if myvar == single:
        something = "This"
    else:
        something = "That"
    return something

mysomething = condfunc(single)
```

I keep getting:

```
NameError: name 'single' is not defined
```

Comment: Did you want to test against the string `"single"`?

Comment: It's really hard to tell what you're trying to do here. Can you post a real example?

Comment: This is the exact example except that there is code unrelated to the macro variable in the "this", "that", and "something" fields.  

Single doesn't contain anything, I just want to use it to select which set of code to execute.  So if the parameter is = "single" than it does the first thing.  If the parameter is "double" it does the other thing.

Comment: In SAS I could do:
%let myvar = single;
%if &myvar = single %then %do;
code
%end;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to test which of two strings the argument `myvar` is? In that case, the code should look like:

```
def condfunc(myvar):
    if myvar == "single":
        something = "This"
    else:
        something = "That"
    return something
```

which can be simplified to:

```
def condfunc(myvar):
    return "This" if myvar == "single" else "That"
```

and you would call it, e.g.:

```
test = "single"
mysomething = condfunc(test)
```

Comment: Thank you.  I also had to put single in quotes in the call as well.  I knew the answer would be something simple.  Moving to a new language can be tough :)